# Summation - Intermixing a change of variable with original notation

Tags: summation, notation, change-of-variable

The change of variable operation is illustrated by the following equation:

$$\sum_{R(i)}a_i = \sum_{R(j)}a_j = \sum_{R(p(i))}a_{p(j)}$$

The equation represents two kinds of transformations:

1. Changing the name of the index variable from $i$ to $j$: $\sum_{R(i)}a_i = \sum_{R(j)}a_j$
2. Replacing the index by some permutation of its values, represented by $p(j)$: $\sum_{R(i)}a_i = \sum_{R(p(i))}a_{p(j)}$, where, for each integer $i$ satisfying the relation $R(i)$, there must be exactly one integer $j$ satisfying the relation $p(j) = i$.

An example that utilises the first kind of transformation is then provided as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
S_1 = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{i}a_ia_j & = \sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{i=j}^{n}a_ia_j &&\text{(change of order)}
\\& = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=i}^{n}a_ia_j &&\text{(change of variable)}
\end{align*}$$

In the second line, we have interchanged the names of $i$ and $j$ (recognising $a_ja_i = a_ia_j$). If we denote the latter sum by $S_2$, we have

$$2S_1 = S_1 + S_2 = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{i}a_ia_j + \sum_{j=i}^{n}a_ia_j\right)$$

**Question**

I'm confused by the stuff in the brackets - why are we allowed to add the change-of-variable sum to the original sum?

If we assume $n=5$, then $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{i}a_ia_j$ denotes the sum of all the yellow terms below:

[image: ![enter image description here]

But how do we know that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{i=j}^{n}a_ia_j$ denotes the sum of the same terms and not these:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Is this implied by simply denoting the second sum by $S_2$ ($S_2$ denoting the same series, but with its order flipped)?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I think the whole point is that the 2 diagrams you have provided are the same sum

Comment: Thanks @AlanAbraham, I understand that they denote the same sum, but I'm just confused by the variable switch as I've never encountered it before (I haven't studied much maths). I've added numbers to the diagrams.

Comment: The number in the cell $(i,j)$ is supposed to represent the product $a_ia_j$, right? So shouldn't the numbers in the square by symmetric about the diagonal?

Comment: Oops, I thought I had corrected that, is it still wrong?

Comment: Like in the table with the yellow highlight. The cell in row "1" and column "0" should have the same entry as the cell in the row "0" and column "1".

Comment: Yes, that's the third table - it shows the values flipped along the diagonal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134697/discussion-between-alan-abraham-and-user51462).